# Observable Collection replace item

Tags: wpf, binding, replace, observablecollection

I have a `ObservableCollection`, I can add and remove item from the collection. But I can't replace an existing item in the collection. There is a way to replace an item and reflect that on my bound components.

```
System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace
```

Can anyone please show me how to accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I update a single item in an ObservableCollection class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781192/how-do-i-update-a-single-item-in-an-observablecollection-class)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
collection[someIndex] = newItem;
```

Comment: I did achive this by implementing  this class
public class MyObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> 
    {

        public MyObservableCollection()
        {

        }
        public MyObservableCollection(List<T> collection)
        {
            MyObservableCollection<T> mb = new MyObservableCollection<T>();

            for (int x = 0; x < collection.Count; x++)
                this.Add(collection[x]);


        }

        public void Replace(int index, T item)
        {
            base.SetItem(index, item);

        }


    }

Comment: You don't need to make your own class.  You can just write `collection[someIndex] = newItem`.

Comment: This answer doesn't work when I try it. This answer does work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781192/how-do-i-update-a-single-item-in-an-observablecollection-class. Is this something to do with the way the object is referenced?

Comment: Replacing an item by using an index doesn't update the UI for me.

Answer (score 6):

**Updated: Indexer uses overridden SetItem and notifies about changes.**

<del>I think the answer about using indexer may be **wrong**, because the question was about **replace and notify**.</del>

Just to clarify: `ObservableCollection<T>` uses indexer from its base `Collection<T>` class, which in turn is a wrapper of `List<T>`, which is a wrapper of simple array of `T`. And there's no override for indexer method in [ObservableCollection](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs,281923b8611114ec) implementation.

So when you use indexer to replace an item in **ObservableCollection** it invokes the following code from **Collection** class:

```
public T this[int index] {
        get { return items[index]; }
        set {
            if( items.IsReadOnly) {
                ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException(ExceptionResource.NotSupported_ReadOnlyCollection);
            }

            if (index < 0 || index >= items.Count) {
                ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }

            SetItem(index, value);
        }
```

It just checks boundaries and calls SetItem that uses indexer of underlying **List** class:

```
protected virtual void SetItem(int index, T item) {
        items[index] = item;
    }
```

During assignment there is no call to the `CollectionChanged` event, because underlying collections know nothing of it.

But when you use `SetItem` method, it is called from ObservableCollection class:

```
protected override void SetItem(int index, T item)
    {
        CheckReentrancy();
        T originalItem = this[index];
        base.SetItem(index, item);

        OnPropertyChanged(IndexerName);
        OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, originalItem, item, index);
    }
```

After assignment it calls `OnCollectionChanged` method, which fires `CollectionChanged` event with `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace` action parameter.

```
    protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
        {
            using (BlockReentrancy())
            {
                CollectionChanged(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

As a conclusion: the idea with custom class inherited from ObservableCollection and `Replace` method that calls `base.SetItem()` worth a try.

Comment: Operator [] uses overridden method SetItem from ObservableCollection

Comment: Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Simple extension method for replace item in observable collection:

```
public static void ReplaceItem<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, T newItem)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (predicate(items[i]))
        {
            items[i] = newItem;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```