# Add an object to the existing observable collection - UWP C#

Tags: c#, uwp, observablecollection

I have a class like below.

```
public class SchoolLeaderDetailsList
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string StudentPassOutDate { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<StudentsMarksList> StudentsMarksArray { get; set; }
}

public class StudentMarksList
{
    public string SubID { get; set; }
    public string Marks { get; set; }
}
```

This class will contain always a single student details with score she got in multiple subjects.Initially I'm assigning all data to the class except the StudentPassOutDate. and assign it to an observable collection .

```
public static ObservableCollection<SchoolLeaderDetailsList> _SchoolLeaderDetailsList = new ObservableCollection<SchoolLeaderDetailsList>();
```

Now when checking the count of _SchoolLeaderDetailsList it is one. 
But after executing some other functions, I have to add StudentPassOutDate to existing data.

I have added StudentPassOutDate as shown below

```
 SchoolLeaderDetailsList objSchoolLeaderDetailsList = new SchoolLeaderDetailsList();   
 objSchoolLeaderDetailsList.StudentPassOutDate="22-05-18";
_SchoolLeaderDetailsList.Add(objSchoolLeaderDetailsList);
```

It is adding as count of two to the collection.
I know that Add function will add an object to the end of collection. so that the count get as two. Then how can I add it to the already existing data?

Comment: I don't see the need of adding a new object, can't you just update the existing one(s) ? See also: [How do I update a single item in an ObservableCollection class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781192/how-do-i-update-a-single-item-in-an-observablecollection-class)

Comment: "This class will contain always a single student details" - then there should not be an ObservableCollection at all. Instead, declare a single property of type StudentsMarksList, and make StudentsMarksList implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, so that changes of its properties update the UI.