# WPF - Binding ObservableCollection to a ListView creates flickering when the mouse is on an item

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, websocket, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection bound to a ListView with about 190 items. Each item is updated from a websocket which means that new information is coming constantly. When I go over the list with the mouse the ListView flickers and if I scroll through the list with the keyboard it starts from the first item again after every update. My assumption was that every time an update comes I create a new ObservableCollection, so the ListView goes from being full to being empty(flickers) to being full again but when I click on an item it focuses and the focus stays without flickering and it updates as expected. What could be causing that? Here is my code:

The ViewModel

```
 public List<Tickers> ListTickers = new List<Tickers>();

        private WSFuturesResponse _futuresResponse;

        public WSFuturesResponse FuturesResponse
        {
            get
            {
                return _futuresResponse;
            }
            set
            {
                _futuresResponse = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FuturesResponse");
                foreach (var future in ListTickers)
                {
                    if (future.Market == FuturesResponse.market)
                    {
                        future.Price = FuturesResponse.data.last;
                    }
                }
                Tickers = new ObservableCollection<Tickers>(ListTickers);
            }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<Tickers> _tickers;
        public ObservableCollection<Tickers> Tickers
        {
            get
            {
                return _tickers;
            }
            set
            {
                _tickers = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Tickers");
            }
        }
// the method that fills the ListTickers
private async void StartConnection(Ticker wsApi, Client client, FtxRestApi api)
        {
            // get all futures data from the API
            var futures = await api.GetAllFuturesAsync();
            // parse the data
            ApiFuturesResponse all_futures = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiFuturesResponse>(futures);

            wsApi.OnWebSocketConnect += () =>
            {
                wsApi.SendCommand(FtxWebSocketRequestGenerator.GetAuthRequest(client));
                foreach (ApiFuturesData future in all_futures.result)
                {
                    if (future.name.Contains("PERP"))
                    {
                        ListTickers.Add(new Tickers(future.name));
                        wsApi.SendCommand(FtxWebSocketRequestGenerator.GetSubscribeRequest("ticker", future.name));
                    }
                }
            };

            await wsApi.Connect();
        }

// the event that updates the properties
public void WebsocketOnMessageReceive(object o, MessageReceivedEventArgs messageReceivedEventArgs)
        {
            FuturesResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WSFuturesResponse>(messageReceivedEventArgs.Message);
        }
```

XAML

```
<ListView Grid.Row="2"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Tickers}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockMarket" Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Text="{Binding Market}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockPrice" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Text="{Binding Price}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The bad experience is the result of replacing the data source of the `ListView`. Assigning a new instance to the source property will always result in a complete reset of the `ItemsControl`. You will experience the heavy performance impact as sluggish UI that will even freeze if the collection is big enough or the `ItemsControl` doesn't support UI virtualization.
   The reason why the `ObservableCollection` is used is that it allows modifying the source collection while the data binding engine can listen to the changes to trigger the `ItemsControl` to update itself. If you replace the complete collection instance instead, the `ObservableCollection` is in fact redundant.
2. In addition, because you are already enumerating the new source collection `ListTickers` in the `foreach`, adding each item directly to the `Tickers` collection will further improve the performance as you eliminate the second enumeration when passing the collection to the constructor of the `ObservableCollection`. Modifying the `Tickers` collection directly (in the same iteration) will therefore solve two performance related problems.
3. A serious source for a bug is that your `async` method `StartConnection` returns `void`. `async` methods must always return a `Task` so that they can be awaited properly. The *only* exception are event handlers, as they must be `void`.
   Because your current implementation returns `void`, you obviously don't `await` it. But you must always await `async` methods to avoid unexpected behavior.
4. Furthermore, keep your properties free from long running tasks or enumerations. In your case, consider to move the enumeration of the `ListTickers` collection and the updating of the `Tickers` collection to the `WebsocketOnMessageReceive` event handler.
5. You always want to keep the visual tree of the items i.e. the `ItemTemplate` simple to improve rendering performance. You currently define three columns but only use two. Consider to use `HorizontalAlignment` instead. `Grid` is an expensive panel too. DockPanel or `StackPanel` are both cheaper. Also consider to drop the element names from the `TextBlock` elements as they force the implicit creation of fields.
6. It's not clear what API you are using to send the request. But it appears like you are mixing APIs. Hard to believe that an async API requires you to use events to obtain the result. Maybe you should check this. Awaiting `Connect()` should replace the `OnWebSocketConnect` event.
7. Using the .NET [`JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserializeasync?view=net-6.0) or the [`System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-6.0) namespace in general will give you async JSON handling: [How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

Always modify the existing `ObservableCollection` instance instead of replacing it:

```cs
public WSFuturesResponse FuturesResponse
{
  get => _futuresResponse;
  set
  {
    _futuresResponse = value;

    // Use 'nameof' to avoid typos and to enable the usage of refactoring tools 
    // e.g. to rename the property.
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FuturesResponse));

    // Clear the data source and reuse it
    Tickers.Clear();

    int preloadCount = 20;

    // Take as much as possible, but not more than 'preloadCount'
    AddTickers(ListTickers.Take(preloadCount));

    // Defer adding the remaining items until the ItemsSource has been rendered.
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
      () => AddTickers(ListTickers.Skip(preloadCount)), 
      DispatcherPriority.Background);
  }

  private void AddTickers(IEnuemrable<Tickers> tickers)
  {
    foreach (var future in tickers)
    {
      if (future.Market == FuturesResponse.market)
      {
        future.Price = FuturesResponse.data.last;
      }

      Tickers.Add(future);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thorough response @BionicCode. I am now awaiting the methods and changed the code as you suggested but the problem still persists. When I remove Tickers.Add(future) and simply start adding to the bottom of the list, then there is no flickering. and the UI moves smoothly. Of course that is not what I am looking for. Obviously the problem is when the OC is either cleared or a new instance is created and I can't figure out the source of that problem. When I click on an item the focus stays stable even when the item updates.

Comment: **1)** *"When I remove Tickers.Add(future) and simply start adding to the bottom of the list"* - What do you mean? Tickers.Add will append to the list (add to the bottom). **2)** You can enable container recycling to further improve the performance: `<ListView VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />` .

Comment: **3)** The `ObservableCollection` "effect" is only improving performance if you don't clear it completely and add all items at once. Since you are using UI virtualization, you can add visible items first (usually 10-20 items) and then after the ListView has completed rendering, add the remaining items. I have updated the example accordingly. 2) + 3) should fix your issue. **4)** If this still doesn't help (let me know) then consider to reuse data items too. This way you avoid clearing the collection. Instead you mutate the existing items.

Comment: I couldn't make it work this way either but I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781192/how-do-i-update-a-single-item-in-an-observablecollection-class). Instead of modifying the whole OC I modify a single Ticker object in it. Works very well. Thanks again for your help, it helped me to better understand the problem and to come up with a solution.

Comment: To modify the individual Ticker instances is what i meant with 4). Good you could make it work.

Comment: Don't forget to let your Ticker implement INotifyPropertyChanged.